# Same Model for Two belongs_to Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, associations, model-associations

I have an model `PointOfContact` which `has_many` `Systems`. From the `Systems` side I want to identify the `PointOfContact` as either the `technical_manager` or `project_manager` (or both). While still only keeping the `PointOfContact` 1 time in the DB.

My attempt follows:

```
class System < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project_manager, :class_name => 'PointOfContact'
  belongs_to :technical_manager, :class_name => 'PointOfContact'
end

class PointOfContact < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :systems
end
```

When I run my specs (example follows) I can correctly create the `System` point of contact associations. However, the `PointOfContact` is not aware of its association with System. Why is that?

```
@sys = System.create
@tm = PointOfContact.create
@pm = PointOfContact.create

@sys.project_manager = @pm
@sys.technical_manager = @tm

@pm.systems.should have(1).items #> expected 1 items, got 0
```

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Thanks to jamesw over at RailsForum.com: [Same Model for Two belongs_to Associations](http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=43311%22Same%20Model%20for%20Two%20belongs_to%20Associations%22) a solution has been found.

```
class System < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project_manager, :class_name => 'PointOfContact', :foreign_key => 'project_manager_id'
  belongs_to :technical_manager, :class_name => 'PointOfContact', :foreign_key => 'technical_manager_id'
end

class PointOfContact < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :project_managed_systems, :class_name => 'System', :foreign_key => 'project_manager_id'
  has_many :technical_managed_systems, :class_name => 'System', :foreign_key => 'technical_manager_id'
end
```

Comment: more details on :through relationships on [link](http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association?view=asciicast)

Answer (score 2):

From the Rails documentation:

- https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins
- https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-has-one

Annotated example:

```
# Employee class with two Employee associations
class Employee < ApplicationRecord

  # Employees I manage
  has_many :subordinates, class_name: "Employee",
                          foreign_key: "manager_id"

  # Employee that manages me
  # NOTE: with :manager reference name, foreign_key defaults to "manager_id",
  # hence it is not needed as above. Favor "convention over configuration".
  belongs_to :manager, class_name: "Employee"
end
```