# Ruby on rails multiple joins on the same table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a model that has :

```
Class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
#...
belongs_to :foo_A, :class_name => "Foo"
belongs_to :foo_B, :class_name => "Foo"
```

And I would like to fetch information from table Foo as follows (code will not work):

```
Bar.joins(:foo_A, :foo_B).select("bars.*, foos_a.name as foo_a_name, foos_b.name as foo_b_name").all
```

Of course, there's no foos_a or foos_b table... just the foos table.

Is there a way to do it without writing the whole sql query ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to avoid SQL query as the select method param?

Answer (score 0):

You must set the foreign_key for each belongs_to. See more in [Same Model for Two belongs_to Associations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294775/same-model-for-two-belongs-to-associations)

```
belongs_to :foo_A, :class_name => "Foo", :foreign_key => 'foo_a_id'
belongs_to :foo_B, :class_name => "Foo", :foreign_key => 'foo_b_id'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I have no problem with the association, just with the query I should use when joining the foos table so I can get the name of both foo_a and foo_b.