# Same Model for Two belongs_to Associations migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

How do I create a migration for a model that has two references to the same model.

I have a user model with two roles, buyer and seller, I also have a sales model  so each sale should have one buyer and one seller.

I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294775/same-model-for-two-belongs-to-associations) that would suggest my sales model should look like

```
class Sale < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :buyer, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'buyer_id'
  belongs_to :seller, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'seller_id'
end
```

but I don't know how to create the migration and get it to work...!

Comment: Which database engine do you use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to create the following migration:

```
rails g migration AddBuyerAndSellerToSales buyer:references seller:references
```

This should create the following migration file:

```
class AddBuyerAndSellerToSales < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :sales, :buyer, index: true, foreign_key: true
    add_reference :sales, :seller, index: true, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

If you use a database engine like PostgreSQL you have to tell the engine to which table the foreign key will point.

```
class AddBuyerAndSellerToSales < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :sales, :buyer, index: true   # foreign_key: true <= remove this!
    add_reference :sales, :seller, index: true  # foreign_key: true <= remove this!

    add_foreign_key :sales, :users, column: :buyer_id
    add_foreign_key :sales, :users, column: :seller_id
  end
end
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: that looks good, thanks, Will I be able to call Buyer.sales or Seller.sales?

Comment: No because you don't have a `Buyer` or `Seller` model. If you have these models you have to add the foreign keys for this table to the `sales` table and create then a `one-to-many` relationship. Do you have a `Buyer` or `Seller` model?

Comment: no model, I can't get @user.sales to work, it gives the error ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column sales.user_id does not exist

Comment: Run `rails g migration AddUserToSales user:references` and migrate it. It should work then.

Comment: but don't I already have those columns on the sales table as buyer&seller?

Comment: No you have the columns `buyer_id` and `seller_id`. If you want to use one of them you have to change your `has_many` call in your `User` model. I suppose you want to use the `seller_id` as the foreign key. Then everything you have to do is to change `has_many :sales, foreign_key: :seller_id` in your `User` model.

Comment: You can use one liner for FK though `add_reference :sales, :buyer, foreign_key: { to_table: :users }`

Answer (score 0):

This is called a [self join](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins), and can be created as follows:

```
#app/models/sale.rb
class Sale < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :buyer, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :buyer_id
  belongs_to :seller, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :seller_id
end
```

--

```
$ rails g migration CreateSales

#db/migrate/create_sales______________.rb
class CreateSales < ActiveRecord::Migrate
    def change
        change_table :sales do |t|
           t.references :seller
           t.references :buyer
        end
    end
end

$ rake db:migrate
```