# Rails model associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-associations

I'm having trouble conceptualizing a good way to create associations between two different models within my Rails app.

At the moment I have a **Person** model and a **Note** model. A person can be the author or the subject of a note.  Therefore:

- A **person** can belong to many **notes** (as the subject).
- A **person** can have many **notes** (as the author).
- A **note** belongs to one author (**person**).
- A **note** can have one subject (**person**).

I imagine the app needing to display **Person** profiles, in which we can see all **Notes** that the **Person** has *written*, as well as all **Notes** written *about* the **Person**.

What's the best way to set up this model-association?  Directly, or through an intermediate relationship model?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would do it directly, you can see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34697634/same-model-for-two-belongs-to-associations-migration for reference.

Comment: Can Note has any other subject type except User?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, the cleanest way is to make a note belong to an author and a subject:

```
class Note < ActiveRecord::base
  belongs_to :author, class_name: 'Person', foreign_key: :author_id
  belongs_to :subject, class_name: 'Person', foreign_key: :subject_id
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::base
  has_many :authored_notes, class_name: 'Note', foreign_key: :author_id
  has_many :notes_about_me, class_name: 'Note', foreign_key: :subject_id
end
```

You may want to change the names of the relationships above, but you get the picture.

I know we don't normally think of a note about someone as belonging to the subject of the note. However, from a Rails perspective, the `belongs_to` relationship allows us to place the `subject_id` foreign key on the `notes` table which is the simplest solution.  If you were to use the `has_one` relationship, you would have to create a join table which, in my opinion, adds unnecessary complexity.

Make sure your `notes` table has has two indexed references to the `persons` table called `subject_id` and `author_id`.  You can do that with a migration like this:

```
class AddSubjectAndAuthorToNotes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :notes, :author, index: true
    add_reference :notes, :subject, index: true

    add_foreign_key :notes, :people, column: :author_id
    add_foreign_key :notes, :people, column: :subject_id
  end
end
```