# Rails 4 - how to use "belongs_to" on the same model twice (once with using "foreign_key")?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, foreign-keys, belongs-to

I have a model `Message`:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to ...
  belongs_to ...
  belongs_to :user

  belongs_to :user,  class_name: "User",  foreign_key: "accepted_denied_by_user_id"
end
```

With this setup, if I call:

```
message.user.email
```

I get email of the user who accepted the message, but not who sent it.

If I remove this line:

```
 belongs_to :user,  class_name: "User",  foreign_key: "accepted_denied_by_user_id"
```

and call:

message.user.email

I get the email of a user who sent out the message.

How can I get the email of the sender and also the recipient?

I tried

```
message.accepted_denied_by_user.email
```

but this leads to

```
undefined method `accepted_denied_by_user' for ...
```

Thank you.

Comment: why you need to use `belongs_to :user` twice? It is not a good practice. Because you repeating the code which is not DRY.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294775/same-model-for-two-belongs-to-associations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to name the second association with different name:

```
belongs_to :denied_user,  class_name: "User",  foreign_key: "accepted_denied_by_user_id"
```

and then you will be able to get the info as:

```
message.denied_user.email
```

you shouldn't give two (or more) associations the same name.

when you do `belongs_to :user` it automatically looks for the `User` model.
but when you want to associate it again - just give it some other name, and then specify `class_name: "User"` - so its still looking in the `User` model, but with the `foreign_key` you specified.

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this:

```
belongs_to :user

belongs_to :accepted_denied_by_user,  class_name: "User",  foreign_key: "accepted_denied_by_user_id"
```

Now you should be able to call both `message.user.email` and `message.accepted_denied_by_user.email` for specific cases.